# Describe the subspace $T^{-1}(N)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I got a) and b), but I have no idea about c).
[image]

Comment: So what are the conditions that the last coordinate of $T(v)$ is zero?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}\in T^{-1}(N)\iff\begin{pmatrix}-4x+y\\4x-3y+6z\\2y-4z\end{pmatrix}\in N\iff$$

$$2y-4z=0\iff y=2z\;,\;\;\text{and then}\;\; 4x-6z+6z=4x\;\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there $a\in\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies $T(a)\in N$ and so $T(a)=(x,y,0)$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Well, if we write $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, we know that $2a_2-4a_3=0$. So, every element in $T^{-1}(x,y,0)$ must satisfy this equation - that is $T^{-1}(x,y,0)\subset \{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\mid 2a_2=4a_3\}$.

It's also not hard to see that if a vector $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies this equations, then it is in $T^{-1}(x,y,0)$ and so $T^{-1}(x,y,0)\supset \{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\mid 2a_2=4a_3\}$. It follows that $$T^{-1}(x,y,z)=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3)\mid a_2=2a_3\}.$$